# ObjectAnimator XML determine height of device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, objectanimator

I'm using the below animator for fragment transactions

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:valueType="floatType"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="-1920"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Here, I know the screen size of my device (1920x1080), but how to make it adapt to any screen size?

Here's how I use this animator

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_bottom, R.animator.slide_out_top);
```

Thanks.

**Edit : I'm not using Support Library**

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://trickyandroid.com/fragments-translate-animation/) post for a brief explanation on how you can achieve it with objectAnimator.
Your animation file might something like:

```
<objectAnimator 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" 
    android:propertyName="yFraction" 
    android:valueType="floatType" 
    android:valueFrom="0" 
    android:valueTo="-1.0" 
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
```

Does this help?

Comment: It says `Fraction types not allowed (at 'valueTo' with value '-100%').`

Comment: The fragment moves by just 1px, by using `-1`

Comment: And is there any particular reason you don't want to use the support library? Probably you'll need it anyway later?

Comment: Actually, Fragments got introduced in API level 11 and my app has min supported API level 14. So I decided to go with regular SDK fragments